# SQL counting number of rows between 24 and 1

Tags: sql, count, min, hour

Good day,
I can count the rows between all other hours but cant count from 24 to 1.
is there another way to do this?
I was thinking of adding minutes to count from 24:00 to 24:59

This is what i got i am not sure how to add minutes

```
UPDATE [servera].[DB].[dbo].[tablea]
SET [241] =
(SELECT Count(*) as '241'
FROM [Serverb].[DB].[dbo].[tablea]
WHERE  Date_Timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR,24,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)) AND            
    Date_Timestamp <= DATEADD(HOUR,1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110)) AND
        trigger_loc = 'user')
WHERE LINE = 'clock'
```

Comment: What time is `24:59` ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: 24:00 => 00:00.

Comment: 24:59 oops not a good day. so i can count for 24 hour from 0 to 1

Answer (score 0):

If you add 24 hours to current time that will be next day. i think your where statement is incorrect. try this:

```
UPDATE [servera].[DB].[dbo].[tablea]
SET [241] =
(SELECT Count(*) as '241'
FROM [Serverb].[DB].[dbo].[tablea]
WHERE  Date_Timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR,0,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)) AND            
    Date_Timestamp <= DATEADD(HOUR,1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110)) AND
        trigger_loc = 'user')
WHERE LINE = 'clock'
```